# Null check in VB

Tags: vb.net, null, runtime-error

All I want to do is check if an object is null, but no matter what I do, if it compiles, it throws a `NullReferenceException` just trying to check! Here's what I've done:

```
    If ((Not (comp.Container Is Nothing)) And (Not (comp.Container.Components Is Nothing))) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To comp.Container.Components.Count() - 1 Step 1
            fixUIIn(comp.Container.Components.Item(i), style)
        Next
    End If

    If ((Not IsDBNull(comp.Container)) And (Not IsDBNull(comp.Container.Components))) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To comp.Container.Components.Count() - 1 Step 1
            fixUIIn(comp.Container.Components.Item(i), style)
        Next
    End If

    If ((Not IsNothing(comp.Container)) And (Not IsNothing(comp.Container.Components))) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To comp.Container.Components.Count() - 1 Step 1
            fixUIIn(comp.Container.Components.Item(i), style)
        Next
    End If

    If ((Not (comp.Container Is DBNull.Value)) And (Not (comp.Container.Components Is DBNull.Value))) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To comp.Container.Components.Count() Step 1
            fixUIIn(comp.Container.Components.Item(i), style)
        Next
    End If
```

I've looked through VB books, searched several forums, and everything that SHOULD work doesn't! Sorry for asking such a remedial question, but I just need to know.

Just so you know, the debugger says that the null object is `comp.Container`

Comment: to get things working while you wait for an answer, sometimes things can be refactored to work.. like using a pair of nested Ifs in this case.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Change your `And`s to `AndAlso`s

A standard `And` will test both expressions.  If `comp.Container` is `Nothing`, then the second expression will raise a `NullReferenceException` because you're accessing a property on a null object.

[`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will short-circuit the logical evaluation.  If `comp.Container` is `Nothing`, then the 2nd expression will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 42):

Your code is way more cluttered than necessary.

Replace `(Not (X Is Nothing))` with `X IsNot Nothing` and omit the outer parentheses:

```
If comp.Container IsNot Nothing AndAlso comp.Container.Components IsNot Nothing Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To comp.Container.Components.Count() - 1
        fixUIIn(comp.Container.Components(i), style)
    Next
End If
```

Much more readable. … Also notice that I’ve removed the redundant `Step 1` and the probably redundant `.Item`.

But (as pointed out in the comments), index-based loops are out of vogue anyway. Don’t use them unless you absolutely have to. Use `For Each` instead:

```
If comp.Container IsNot Nothing AndAlso comp.Container.Components IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each component In comp.Container.Components
        fixUIIn(component, style)
    Next
End If
```